# Struts 2 locale seems to default to 'en', how to change?

Tags: internationalization, struts2

Edit to clarify:

If my Struts 2 site is designed to support two languages, and a user comes to the site with a third (unsupported) language, how does the site determine which localisation to use?

If my project lists

- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages.properties` # Contains strings in Danish
- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties` # Contains strings in English

then I would expect Struts to serve the page in Danish to a user whose browser requests it in, say, German. But this is not the case! In reality, the page is served using the strings from the English localisation. Why is that, and how do I modify this?

To be clear, yes if the user requests `http://localhost:8080/project/index.do?request_locale=de` then that obviously does *not* magically provide a German translation. All the same, if they use a German OS and browser, then that will be the language requested in the HTTP header. Given that the site is not able to fulfil that request, how does Struts choose which language to serve? It does not, after all, return the raw i18n keys themselves but the string values from *some* localitation. Which one, and why?

---

How do I set a 'fallback locale' for a Struts 2 site? It seems to prefer 'en' which is not what I want.

My project has the following files:

- `src/main/webapp/jsp/index.jsp`
- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages_da.properties` # Contains strings in Danish
- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties` # Contains strings in English
- `src/main/resources/struts.xml` # Complete xml file, including:

  - `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="i18n.messages" />`

Loading the index page, the preferred language that the user has set in the browser is correctly reflected in the rendered page. The page has links to reload in specific locales (`http://localhost:8080/project/index.do?request_locale=en`) and these also work as expected.

However, if coming to the page with an unsupported locale (by way of one's browser settings, or explicitly via `http://localhost:8080/project/index.do?request_locale=sw`) then the index page is rendered in English. I would prefer this to be in Danish. **How do I set this fallback language?**

Even changing the files to:

- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages.properties`
- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties`

seems to have no effect. Specifically, setting my browser up to use Swahili *only* (so English is not even listed), and accessing the index page without specific parameters, the web page is still rendered in English and not using the strings from the 'bare' i18n file.

I'm hoping there is a setting in `src/main/resources/struts.xml` or `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` that I have missed (as this is my first foray into Struts)?

Comment: It is not clear what you asking. What is  a `fallback locale`? You have just used a wrong URL because you requested a locale that isn't supported by your application. In this case you should display the error and redirect to the right page.

Comment: @RomanC,  I have prepended an alternate explanation, hoping it's clearer now. Also: How would the site know which language to pick when displaying the error? That is what I mean by 'fallback'.

Comment: Still not clear. You can choose any language which is requested by the client and supported by the site.

Comment: @RomanC, please see this from the user perspective - if you visit a site that's localised for languages A, B, and C, but your OS/browser is set up for language D (or at least, neither of A/B/C), which localisation will you be given? Why is that, how is that selection made (by Struts), and can that be configured (by the site developer, not the visitor)?

Comment: What do you mean `but your OS/browser is set up for language`? Why is what? The selection is made not by struts but the user.

Comment: exactly! Consider some random internet user (say, someone located in Poland, with their entire pc set up for Polish language). _They_ have determined that they would like to browse the web in Polish. Visiting their national TV homepage, that works fine. Visiting the Danish national TV homepage? The site (assuming it's not designed to support Polish) would have to determine what _other_ language to serve this user. Polish? No, don't know that. Danish? English? *How does the site make that call?* I don't know why this scenario is so difficult to grasp.

Comment: No, it's not difficult, but your question is impossible to answer because it's off-topic according to the rules on stack overflow.

Comment: How on Earth do you figure it's off topic all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, using a custom `Interceptor`. I would have preferred a simple entry in a configuration file, but this at least works.

```
package my.web.site.i18n;

import java.util.Locale;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class LocaleInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Locale LOCALE_DA = new Locale("da", "DK");
    private static final Locale LOCALE_EN = new Locale("en", "GB");

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    /**
     * When a user requests our site in an un-localised language, we want to respond in Danish.
     *
     * @param invocation the action invocation
     * @return the incoming invocation, possibly with adjusted locale
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        String invocationLanguage = invocation.getInvocationContext().getLocale().getLanguage();
        if (!LOCALE_DA.getLanguage().equals(invocationLanguage)
        &&  !LOCALE_EN.getLanguage().equals(invocationLanguage)
        ) {
            invocation.getInvocationContext().setLocale(LOCALE_DA);
        }
        return invocation.invoke();
    }
}
```